# Dropbox API access from Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building a project which will be using the Dropbox API to read and write files to and from Dropbox. I have noticed that the endpoint URL is linked to an Amazon ELB, and i am wondering is there an AWS internal API i could use, which may save both me and Dropbox some money by making internal to Amazon requests, not external requests?

Answer (score 1):

Host of Dropbox API is `api.dropbox.com` and resolves to 199.47.218.158.

That does not look like it belongs in one of the EC2 public IPs.
See: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1528

Anyway, even if it is, it is not possible to determine the internal IP unless they publish the elastic IP DNS name (that looks like `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`).

A little known tip:
If you query an Elastic IP's DNS name from within an EC2 instance, you will get an internal IP.

Comment: when i do a lookup for api-content.dropbox.com, which is the one which holds the files, i get dl-balancer3-985632286.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com and 8 different IPs back... each come back as amazon compute nodes, for example: ec2-50-19-221-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com. So, maybe just running a DNS query on api-content.dropbox.com, and using the IPs directly might work...

Comment: I tried with `ec2-50-19-221-73.compute-1.amazonaws.com` that you specified. Unfortunately that doesn't work as it's probably not an Elastic IP. It still returns a public IP.